# Retrieve Select2 multi values in Django Views to use in backend

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

I have a working Select2 Multi Dropdown in my html, but how do I bring these value back to Django to use in the backend?

For example in my html, I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#ddlselect").select2({
            placeholder:'Select from List',
            closeOnSelect:false
        });

    });
</script>
```

I then fill the dropdown with the following code:

```
        <select id="ddlselect" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px;">
            {% for item in mylist %}
                <option> {{ item }} </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

This works and I can choose from the dropdown.

I can retrieve the values using the following in html:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Selected value is: "+$("#ddlselect").select2("val"));
}
</script>
```

Now, how do I bring these values back to my Django Views?

I have tried the following -

```
class newoption(TemplateView):

   template_name = 'home/page.html'
   
   def get(self, request):

      return render(request, self.template_name, dict)

   def post(self, response):
        a = response.POST['ddlselect']
```

I get an error trying to return a to use on the backend.  How do I retrieve the selected values from the select2MultiSelect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**getlist()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method:

> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty
> list if the key doesn’t exist and default is None. It’s guaranteed to
> return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.
>
> ```
> self.request.POST.getlist('ddlselect')
> ```

Something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class NewOption(TemplateView):
    
    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ddl = request.POST.getlist('ddlselect')
        ... Some code here ...
        return HttpResponse("Submitted!")
```

Also add `name` attribute to your html select:

```
<select name="ddlselect" id="ddlselect" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px;">
...
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am returning a blank list on my code.  Is there anything else I need to add / consider?

Comment: What did you mean - "I am returning a blank list on my code"?

Comment: The variable ddl returns a blank list instead of the selected values from the multiselect.

Comment: @MC2020, print your `request.POST`. Do you see anything?

Comment: @MC2020, add `name="ddlselect"` to your select

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! This is working for me now.